# Как взять все теги по маске id

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautiful-soup

Я использую python3.6 и библиотеку beautifulsoup4 для парсинга страниц. Как мне получить все теги div у которых id начинается на body_ ?

Answer (score 1):

```
soup.find_all("div", id=re.compile('body_.*'))
```

или

```
soup.find_all(lambda tag: tag.name == 'div' and tag.get('id', '').startswith('body_'))
```

Comment: чтобы только в начале строки регулярное выражение искало, следует `^` добавить. `.*` здесь не нужно.